# How to render landing page with angularjs webapp?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new in angularjs. I am developing a small webapp in angularjs. I use [ui-router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ui-router) to route pages. I also have a landing page which is just static stuff with clickable links.  The landing page covers the entire page, while other pages cover only "`ui-view`" div. I do not know if it's feasible what I am about to ask. Is it possible to use `AngularJS` (ui-router) to render the landing page (full html page) and other pages (partials), if so how, if not, is there a workaround? how to people usually add landing page to their  angularjs app.

Comment: You cannot render the entire page, doing that is equivalent to a full reload. With ui-router, is easy do what you want, you only need to add this: .state('myRoute', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'views/myView.html'
            })

Comment: Study the demos...should answer your questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are a beginner you will get such doubts..

Your `index page` should contain all the parts which should not change after routing to a different page.It can include **navbar, footer, sidebar** etc.
Whatever has to change should be put in `ng-view`.And I would recommend you to put your landing page also in a seperate file and route it at starting..

**I have made a working template...have a look**

https://github.com/pankajofksms/Template